# Email Notification when stylesheet is accessed

Tags: php, css, email

I have this wonderful script for notification of page access :
`<?php mail('email@address.com','My Subject','My Message'); ?>`

Can this be achieved when a stylesheet is accessed?
It seems adding php into a .css causes all kinds of interesting errors  LOL

ADDON - or better yet, can an email be sent when a function() is activated?

Comment: Your webserver won't pass a CSS file to the PHP interpreter for execution by default. You'd have to configure it to do that. But I've no idea why you'd want do. You want a notification every time someone loads your CSS?? Why not just compile a report every day from your webserver's logs?

Comment: ok, i didn't know that was an option. Will look into - TY

Comment: Yep, your webserver will write a line in a log file anytime a file on the server is accessed via a HTTP request.